# JSF: Is there a way to save some component state during a call to `setValueExpression()`?

Tags: java, jsf

We're developing a few JSF Input Field Components. One thing we'd like to do is have the components examine the backing bean for Bean Validation annotations and automatically apply the same validations to the client side.

When `setValueExpression("value", "#{bean.fieldName})` is invoked with the `value` as the first argument, that seems like the correct time to grab the backing bean and read the Bean Validation annotations.

```
    @Override
    public void setValueExpression(final String name, final ValueExpression binding) {
        super.setValueExpression(name, binding);
        if ("value".equals(name)) {
            try {
                final ValueReference valueReference = binding.getValueReference(getFacesContext().getELContext());
                final Object base = valueReference.getBase();
                final String propertyName = valueReference.getProperty().toString();
                final Field declaredField = ElUtils.findDeclaredField(base.getClass(), propertyName);
                if (declaredField != null) {
                    final Set<Class<?>> validationGroups = ElUtils.convertOrDefault(getValidationGroups());
                    final List<Annotation> annotations = ElUtils.getValidatorAnnotations(declaredField, validationGroups);

// we'd like to cache the result of the above reflection code if the valueExpression hasn't changed
getStateHelper().put(PropertyKeys.reflectedOnBinding, binding.getExpressionString());

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

We would really like to avoid that somewhat expensive reflection code, every single request if the valueBinding hasn't changed.

Here's the problem, `getStateHelper().get(PropertyKeys.reflectedOnBinding)` *never* returns the value after the request is complete.

Why does this happen? We've tried 100 different things and can't magically get JSF to save the component state.

Comment: Tried adding what you need to keep to `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getAttributes()`?

Comment: Hey man, can you please leave the Java tag? This absolutely is a Java AND JSF question. Thank you!

Comment: Also, are you saying FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getAttributes() and set the value there? I think we could do that, but since this has to happen for every component, how would we differentiate what expression belongs to which component?

Comment: The question cannot be answered by anyone with Java knowledge only. It will not help you to get it answered. Include the component's clientId in the attribute key.

Comment: I'd prefer to leave it if you don't mind. Regardless:

```
   final String key = "valuexpressioncache." + getClientId();
   final Object stored = getFacesContext().getViewRoot().getAttributes().get(key);
   System.out.println("before:" + stored);
   getFacesContext().getViewRoot().getAttributes().put(key, binding.getExpressionString());
``` 
Does not ever return a key. The view is not marked transient, so we're a little baffled why this happens